# select in non-blocking design of c code

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

in Unix Network Programming by Stevens et al non-blocking sockets are illustrated with code making use of select call. The very same call that usually selects between blocking file descriptors.

My understanding was that non-blocking design was exactly an alternative to select: instead of being blocked in select call, my code could loop checking non-blocking descriptors and performing something else on top of that. Was my understanding wrong or is there anything enigmatic about select call that makes it inevitable in non-blocking design?

Down to practicalities, I need to work with a large number of tcp sockets putting "personal" timeout on each of them. I thought of using non-blocking design and looping through correspondent arrays. Would it be appropriate without select?

Thank you.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. Non-blocking sockets are not designed to do away with blocking on `select`. They are designed to do away with blocking on `send`, `recv`, `connect` and other operations. Of those `connect` is particularly troublesome as with blocking sockets it cannot be multiplexed by `select`. With non-blocking sockets you can eliminate `select` entirely, or can use it whenever it makes sense, and use periodic checks in other cases.

Comment: What do you mean, 'putting personal timeout on each of them'? Do you mean that each socket has a customizable inactivity timer after which the connection is dropped?

Comment: @n.m. Thank you, this is actually exactly what i wanted be sure at: possibility of elimination of select call with non-blocking sockets.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson Yes, this is exactly what I mean, sorry if i didn't make myself clear enough

Comment: Your statement 'that usually selects between blocking sockets' is just guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A customizable inactivity timer shouldn't really have anything to do with the `select()` call. maintain your array of timers separately, update them on every tick, or every <x> iterations through your event loop, reset any timer each time the associated socket has activity, close it when inactivity reaches threshold. That's got nothing whatsoever to do with how you actually handle input/output.

Whether or not you use [`select()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) is orthogonal to whether you use non-blocking sockets. `select()` isn't there to keep you from blocking on reads, after all. What `select()` is for is to keep you from blocking *when you don't want to*. (And not just on reads: you can always call `select()` with a zero timeout, and `select()` won't block either). Also, it provides a mechanism for knowing when there's input that's much more efficient than "iterate over my entire set of sockets, trying a nonblocking [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) on each one in turn".

Comment: Aha! so this is where I'm stumped, why select is more efficient than just combing through descriptors in non-blocking mode? Besides, what is upper limit of number of descriptors - it is not that much for select - is it?

Comment: The upper limit for descriptors that `select()` can handle is slightly more than a thousand, but if that's a problem, your OS will generally have implementation-specific alternatives that provide the capability for a larger set.

Comment: As for why `select()` is more efficient, I would tend to assume that it's because `select()` isn't actually performing a try/fail to read on _every single file descriptor sequentially_, it's just asking the kernel "is there pending input on any of these?" and passing the answer back to you, where you can then perform a read specifically on the subset of descriptors for which there is actually input.